# how to use gsub with awk to apply on all strings

Tags: awk

I'm trying to use `gsub` with `awk` to apply on all strings but failed.

`gsub(/^ *| *$/,"", $4);`

instead of applying this for string `$4`, i would like to apply it with all strings. i tried with `$0` but failed.

What's wrong?

```
awk '{ 
     split($12, a, /[/:]/); 
     if (length(a[2]) == 1) $12=sprintf("%s:%02d/%d", a[1], a[2], a[3]);
     gsub(/^ *| *$/,"", $0);
     print $9, $12, $10, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $13 
 }' FS='|' OFS=',' file
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
|f_name:x|l_name:x| address:x x | city:x |state:x|zip:x|country:x|ordernumber:x|code:x|downloaded:x| exp:9/2017|ip:x.x.x.x|
```

**Output**

```
ordernumber:x,exp:09/2017,code:x,f_name:x,l_name:x,address:x x,city:x,state:x,zip:x,country:x,ip:x.x.x.x
```

Comment: you can iterate over all fields applying that `gsub` call. For relatively simple input strings I would also try sed substitution

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest got it so it's can't applied to all without iterate ?

Comment: @Sundeep done :)

Answer (score 1):

Loop from `1` to `NF` and refer to the field with `$i` (or whatever you use to name the loop counter). The syntax is similar to C:

```
for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) {
    ...
}
```

E.g.

```
$ echo "  foo bar  :doh : bla:" |awk -vOFS=: -F: '
    { for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) gsub(/^ +| +$/, "", $i) } 1'
foo bar:doh:bla:
```

(I changed `/^ */` to `/^ +/` as `mawk` seems to ignore the `^` in the former.)

Comment: i will update my question since that solution not working with me.

Comment: @meuh take a look after the update on my question

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is remove whitespace from each field, where the fields are separated by the character "|", then simply change the field delimeter to include that whitespace. Assuming your awk supports a regexp as field separator, replace your `FS='|'` setting with

```
FS=' *\\| *'
```

Note the need to escape the `|` as the strings is now a pattern.

This does not handle whitespace at the start of the first field, and end of the last field.  You can use `sub(/^ */,"",$1)` and `sub(/ *$/,"",$NF)` on these.

Comment: to implement this: `echo "  foo bar  :doh : bla:" |awk -vOFS=: -F' *: *' '{gsub(/^ *| *$/,""); $1=$1; print}'` -- the `$1=$1` bit is required to rewrite the string to convert the input field separators to the output field separators.